# Swift Duplicate Method(Code Pattern)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm New In Application, So I Don't Know about Swift Design Pattern(Coding Pattern)

I'm Using duplicate Function about

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`

this same method are used for many controller.

How Can I reduce same code? (tell me if i make class, and ... some right way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would say you are not duplicating the code here.
See the explaination below.

```
func prepareForSegue(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender sender: AnyObject?)
```

is an opportunity to configure the new view controller prior to it being displayed. It contains information about the transition, including references to both view controllers that are involved.

This will not be same in all ViewControllers. Like if some of your ViewController may need information from previous ViewController (consider you are passing some information from VC1 -> VC2) and some may not.

If you are not passing information from Source VC to Destination VC or do not configure Destination VC before presenting you can avoid overriding this method.

For more information see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:).

Comment: Thanks, For Your Help :)